# Recursive Function : Check for palindrome in Java

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

I have a class that checks whether a string is a palindrome or not. I have two questions.

1) Is this the most efficient way to check for palindrome? 
2) Can this be implemented recursively?

```
public class Words {

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    String pal = null;
    word = word.replace(" ", "");
    pal = new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString();
    if (word.compareTo(pal) == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    }

}
```

Have a test class to test this... Doubt its needed but here it is anyways if anyone cares to try it out to be able to help me with any of the two questions above...

```
public class testWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (Words.isPalindrome("a") == true) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    if (Words.isPalindrome("cat") == true) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    if (Words.isPalindrome("w o    w") == true) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    if (Words.isPalindrome("   a  ") == true) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    if (Words.isPalindrome("mom!") == true) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }

    }

}
```

thanks in advance for any help and or input :)

Comment: You might want to change what you consider to be valid characters when deciding if a phrase is a palindrome. For example, "Madam, I'm Adam" is a palindrome.

Comment: so i should try to get my program to ignore characters such as " ' "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579977/palindrome-recursion-program?rq=1

Comment: First, filter out all the non-alphanumeric characters, then check for it being a palindrome.

Comment: `return (word.compareTo(pal) == 0)` saves on the `if`.

Comment: And in the test code you can equally say ```System.out.println("" + Words.isPalindrome("whatever"))``` -- a boolean will convert to the string "true" or "false" appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To implement a 'palindrome check' recursively, you must compare if the first and last characters are the same. If they are not the same the string is most certainly not a palindrome. If they are the same the string might be a palindrome, you need to compare the 2nd character with the 2nd to last character, and so on until you have strictly less then 2 characters remaining to be checked in your string.

A recursive algorithm would look like this:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
  //Strip out non-alphanumeric characters from string
  String cleanWord = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");
  //Check for palindrome quality recursively
  return checkPalindrome(cleanWord);
}
private static boolean checkPalindrome(String word) {
  if(word.length() < 2) { return true;  }
  char first  = word.charAt(0);
  char last   = word.charAt(word.length()-1);
  if(  first != last  ) { return false; }
  else { return checkPalindrome(word.substring(1,word.length()-1)); }
}
```

- Note, that my *recursion* method is not most efficient approach, but
  simple to understand
- **[Marimuthu Madasamy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15722948/1465011)** has a more efficient *recursive* method, but is harder to understand
- **[Joe F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15722738/1465011)** has listed an equivalently efficient *iterative* method
  which is the **best** approach for implementation because it cannot cause a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) error

Comment: +1 This seems correct, would you mind explaining to OP why this works?

Comment: I think you mean word.length() < 2 for your base case.

Comment: @bluevoid if it was a homework question, as long as he learns from my answer it does not harm, but rather advances his education.

Comment: Your right, I was just kiddin, maybe I am just jealous that i never thought of asking for help on a forum like this when i was doing my computer science study. Plus one for your answer by the way.

Comment: @awashburn can you explain what this line of code does? (Particularly the last part...) ` String cleanWord = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");`

Comment: @awashburn also, shouldnt the return "internalPalindromeCheck" what is that :S

Comment: Darn I thought I fixed that, `internalPalindromeCheck` should have been the `checkPalindrome` method.

Comment: @choloboy7 the `word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");` is a statement telling java to take the string, find all non alphanumeric characters, and replace them with the empty string. The confusing part I assume is `"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"`. This called a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (RegEx), they are a powerful and versatile tool. Definitely worth learning in time.

Comment: @awashburn oh i see, so what is in the brackets is simply specifying what should be replaced! gotcha :)

Comment: @choloboy7 this particular regular expression `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` says match everything that is not `^` a letter `a-zA-Z` or a number `0-9`

Comment: plus one for you my friend :) i appreciate all the help

Answer (score 6):

Here is another recursive solution but using array which could give you some performance advantage over string in recursive calls (avoiding `substring` or `charAt`).

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(final char[] chars, final int from,
        final int to) {
    if (from > to) return true;
    return chars[from] != chars[to] ? false 
                                    : isPalindrome(chars, from + 1, to - 1);
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(final String s) {
    return isPalindrome(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length() - 1);
}
```

The idea is that we keep track of two positions in the array, one at the beginning and another at the end and we keep moving the positions towards the center.

When the positions overlap and pass, we are done comparing all the characters and all the characters so far have matched; the string is palindrome.

At each pass, we compare the characters and if they don't match then the string is not palindrome otherwise move the positions closer.

Comment: Your solution is elegant, but I fear it is to obtuse for a beginner to understand intuitively. Perhaps add some comments?

Comment: sure, let me expand that a bit.

Answer (score 5):

It's actually sufficient to only check up to the middle character to confirm that it is a palindrome, which means you can simplify it down to something like this:

```
// Length of my string.
int length = myString.length();

// Loop over first half of string and match with opposite character.
for (int i = 0; i <= length / 2; i++) {
    // If we find one that doesn't match then return false.
    if (myString.charAt(i) != myString.charAt(length - 1 - i)) return false;
}

// They all match, so we have found a palindrome!
return true;
```

A recursive solution is very possible but it is not going to give you any performance benefit (and probably isn't as readable).

Comment: I dont understand. Would one not need to check the second half of the word??? How can checking up to middle character guarantee it is a palindrome?

Comment: @choloboy7 Because you already checked the second half; When you check the first character you compare it to the last, when you compare the 2nd character you compare it to the 2nd to last. When you reach the middle all characters have been compared.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be implemented Recursively?

**YES**
Here is example:

```
public static boolean palindrome(String str)
{
    if (str.length()==1 || str.length == 0)
    return true;
    char c1 = str.charAt(0);
    char c2 = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
    if (str.length() == 2)
    {
        if (c1 == c2)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
    if (c1 == c2)
    return palindrome(str.substring(1,str.length() - 1));
    else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @awashburn: can you tell me those words apart from 0 length word where it fails?

Comment: so it means except for 0 length word, it is working fine for all other words..right?

Answer (score 1):

My two cents. It's always nice to see the different ways people solve a problem. Of course this is not the most efficient algorithm memory or speed wise.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

    if (s.length() <= 1) { // got to the middle, no need for more checks
        return true;
    }

    char l = s.charAt(0); // first char
    char r = s.charAt(s.length() - 1); // last char

    if (l == r) { // same char? keep checking
        String sub = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
        return isPalindrome(sub);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check palindrome.

```
private static String palindromic(String word) {
    if (word.length() <= 1) {
        return "Polidramic";
    }else if (word.charAt(0) != word.charAt(word.length() - 1)) {
        return "Not Polidramic";
    }
    return palindromic(word.substring(1, word.length() - 1));
}
```